# The [ ] symbol for arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am working my way through a book, and I noticed something I don't really understand.

```
static void qsort(char items[]) {
    qs(items, 0, items.length -1); }
```

So in this code, you pass an array to a method to initiate another method. The thing which I do not really get is: you pass an array in `qsort(char items[]) //Items with [] brackets` , but you pass just `items //Without [] brackets` to qs method.

I've had a look in the book and it never mentions this. If I was passing an array here, intuitively I think it would look like `qs(items[], 0, items.length -1)`, but that yields an error.

So what exactly am I passing here as `items`?

Comment: It's just an issue of readability. `char items[]` and `char[] items` are equivalent. Here the author is electing to write `items[]` to indicate it being an array. However, some would argue it is more confusing (as in your case) and prefer `char[] items` since most people read left to right anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char[]` is the type of `items`. `items` is still just a normal variable, and you can reference it by just using its name. (In essence, the `[]` is used when declaring a variable of array type, or when indexing into it -- e.g. `items[0]` or `items[items.length - 1]`.)

Comment: Also the delacrations `char[] items` and `char items[]` are equivalent

Comment: Simple question, simple answer, thanks. It is more clear to just declare every type as a 'type[] var' rather than 'type var[]'.

Answer (score 0):

> you pass an array in qsort(char items[]) //Items with [] brackets

`qsort(char items[])` is `qsort` method signature, it means `qsort` will accept an `array` or `char` ie it will accept an `char[]` as argument.

> but you pass just items //Without [] brackets to qs method.

you are calling `qs` method here like `qs(items, 0, items.length -1)`, so the variable of `char[]` you have declared here is `items` so you are passing it, as it is an `char[]`.

> `qs(items[], 0, items.length -1)`, but that yields an error.

`qs` methods accepts an `char[]`. Here `items` is an `char[]` not `items[]`. Also note that `char items[]` is similar to `char[] items` , just a matter of writing, both are legal, but make your choice to stick to one & don't get confused. So as a matter of passing `char[]` variable you can pass `items` not `items[]`.